# Alamofire Extra argument 'method' call

Tags: swift3, alamofire

```
let params = "name=Thobio Joseph&googleid=24356567890uyy4546&email=jthobio2@gmail.com&avatar=https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrinknp_200_200/AAEAAQAAAAAAAAv0AAAAJDZjZGJjMTFjLWNiNzAtNGYzNy1iMDE4LTA2MzBmNzUwZGExNQ.jpg"

func postMethodUploadDataToServerLoginPage() {

Alamofire.request(loginUrl, method:.post,parameters:params.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8),encoding:URLEncoding.default).responseJSON { response in

switch response.result {

case .success:
                print(response)

case .failure(let error):
                failure(0,"Error")

}

}
```

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do, and the problem you might be facing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First your params are wrong you need to pass a dictionary `[key:value]` and then you need to convert it to json and put in your request body, also if you are using `Alamofire.request` you don't need pass urlString, only a request, try with this code

```
func postMethodUploadDataToServerLoginPage() {

let paramToSend = ["name":"Thobio Joseph","googleid":"24356567890uyy4546","email":"jthobio2@gmail.com","avatar":"https://media.licdn.com/mpr/mpr/shrinknp_200_200/AAEAAQAAAAAAAAv0AAAAJDZjZGJjMTFjLWNiNzAtNGYzNy1iMDE4LTA2MzBmNzUwZGExNQ.jpg"]

let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: URL(string: loginUrl)!)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.httpBody = try! JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters)

Alamofire.request(request).responseJSON { (response) in

switch response.result {

case .success:
                print(response)

case .failure(let error):
                failure(0,"Error")

}

}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: what if the php post method is like $_POST['name'],$_post['email'] will it take the json

Comment: @ThobioJoseph did you try my answer?, must work, try it and let me know

Comment: @ThobioJoseph if my answer solves your problem please accept it

Comment: responseSerializationFailed(Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.jsonSerializationFailed(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.}))
responseSerializationFailed(Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.jsonSerializationFailed(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid value around character 0." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid value around character 0.}))

Comment: @ThobioJoseph your response json is invalid, please check that